# Local device testing issues with xip.io

Tags: php, apache, mamp, xip.io

Related to the unresolved question at [xip.io with MAMP Pro doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546356/xip-io-with-mamp-pro-doesnt-work)
This is a real head-scratcher with not much supporting documentation online. After 7 hours of fruitless research, I'm turning to you guys. Please help!

The goal: locally test websites that I have developed on my MacBook with other devices (phone/tablet) on my network. I want to use virtual hosts so that I can access different sites by unique name. e.g. localhost.dev, local.timreader.com etc
I'm attempting to use the xip.io service to assist. And I'm running Mamp Pro V2 as the server.

So first of all, what *is* working:

- The virtual hosts, as set up in Mamp Pro, on my local machine
- The  xip.io address on my local machine /sometimes/ resolves but not
  always    e.g localhost.x.x.x.x.xip.io
- Direct access to    the    webserver root from devices e.g.
  http://x.x.x.x

And what *isn't* working:

- Accessing the website via the xip.io address from non-local devices
  (locahost.x.x.x.x.xip.io/)

I'm on Mountain Lion (have re-enabled the Web Sharing preference - which Apple hid - and tried it both on and off - I think off is correct? Although I'm confused as to how that impacts access from external machines).

Willing to try anything and everything so all ideas welcome!

Comment: Did you make any progress on this? I got this solution working, let me know if you're still stuck.

Comment: I was just about to post this exact question. I'm having the same issue and I can't find any documentation or help... anywhere. @VolkerRose please provide an answer if you have one! I'm sure myself, Tim, and others are in need of a solution.

Comment: Just as a side note, I tried using [proxylocal](http://proxylocal.com/) to achieve the desired result. Unfortunately it gave me the exact same results.

Comment: I would like to help, but could you be a bit more concrete? Where/are you able to ping the xip.io address from your non-local device? Did you try accessing it via cURL?

Comment: Ah, I just read a possible important part of Tims question: "xip.io address from **non-local devices**". Xip.io just points back to your local IP, so you won't be able to reach the xip.io address from devices that aren't on your local network.

Answer (score 2):

I just read a possible important part of Tims question: "xip.io address **from non-local devices**". Xip.io just points back to your local IP, so you won't be able to reach the xip.io address from devices that aren't on your local network.